# Format Kubernetes Yaml file into VSCode

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, format

I have a Kubernetes YAML file, which I copied from PDF file. It should be nice, if I could format the file in order to have the correct indentation of the k8s file

What I have now:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: minimal-ingress
annotations:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
ingressClassName: nginx-example
rules:
- http:
paths:
- path: /testpath
pathType: Prefix
backend:
service:
name: test
port:
number: 80
```

What would I like to have

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Additional information: from my current vscode (1.73.1) I have already installed both the following extensions

```
Name: YAML
Id: redhat.vscode-yaml
Description: YAML Language Support by Red Hat, with built-in Kubernetes syntax support
Version: 1.10.1
Publisher: Red Hat
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml
```

and

```
Name: Kubernetes YAML Formatter
Id: kennylong.kubernetes-yaml-formatter
Description: A better YAML formatter for DevOps like Kubernetes, Ansible, CI/CD, etc.
Version: 1.1.0
Publisher: kennylong
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kennylong.kubernetes-yaml-formatter
```

In particular from the last one, that seems to be what I found, does not work.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there actually an extension for this purpose?

Comment: yaml syntax depends on indentation, vey hard for a format tool to decide what the indentation should be, do I add the entry to a dictionary/object deep in the tree or at the first object, very different results